# Retrieving model objects created by different users in Django

Tags: python, django

I am making simple feed which consists of entries made by authors which current user is subscribed to. I have 3 models which are default user model, my "Post" model which is related to User via ForeignKey:

```
class Post(models.Model):
...
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="posts")
...
```

"Relations" model which has 2 fields:

```
follower = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="follows")
following = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="followed")
```

So I wrote this code to retrieve needed posts:

```
user = request.user
posts = Post.objects.filter(author__in = [relation.following_id for relation in user.follows.all()]).all()
```

And honestly it works just fine, but is there any way to make my query better? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can make the JOIN in the database, so:

```
Post.objects.filter(author__followed__follower=user)
```

or if you want to include `Post` objects for which `user` is the `author`, you can work with `Q`-objects:

```
from django.db.models import Q

Post.objects.filter(Q(author=user) | Q(author__followed__follower=user))
```

Since you do the JOIN at the database side, you do this in *one* query, wheras the list comprehension will be performed in *2* queries.